# Que no se repita un valor condicional de un *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema dentro de un ngfor, hasta el momento cumple con los valores, pero me gustaría que al ser mayor o igual a 9 la condición Todos solo se repita una vez y que todas las claves del programa se muestre en el tooltip.

Hasta ahora es todo lo que tengo, cuando no cumple se muestra por separado y la clave respectiva, pero si deseo que cuando estén todas se cumpla la otra condición y en el tooltip muestre todos los nombres de los programas separadas por coma.

```
<div *ngFor="let clave of Proyecto.j_programa" class="listar_programas">
   <span pTooltip="{{clave.programa}}" tooltipPosition="bottom" class="font-bold">{{ Proyecto.j_programa?.length  >= 9 ? 'Todos' : clave.clave_programa+', '}}</span>
</div>
```

De igual forma no se como usar la funcion join en la variable **clave.clave_programa** ya que actualmente lo concateno así > +', ' y deseo que el último elemento tenga un punto o no muestre nada.

**Actualmente imprime así:**
GA, IA, II,

**algo así:**
GA, IA, II.

Leí que con .join pero me da me da el resultado y se bugea todo.

Comment: Opcionalmente puedes preparar todos tus datos antes de hacer el bucle con ngFor. De está manera tendrás todas las operaciónes disponibles. La limitante que tienes es por que no todo está permitido ejecutarlo en las plantillas de html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes no renderizar la página hasta que las operaciones asincronas terminen con un `*ngIf`. Simplemente agregalo en la parte más alta de la jerarquia.

```html
<div *ngIf="movieDetails"  #moviedetails class="movie-details">

  <section class="header" >
      <app-header [data]="movieDetails"></app-header>
  </section>

 ...MAS CODIGO...
```